# How to handle youtube api method errors in python?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, youtube, youtube-api

When I do the [`PlaylistItems.insert()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) method, how can I handle the [`videoNotFound`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#errors) error? In addition, how can I handle other errors at the same time like `IndexError`?

```
try:
    result = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part = "snippet",
        body = {
            "snippet": {
                "playlistId": MY_PLAYLIST_ID,
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": MY_VIDEO_ID
                }
            }
        }
    ).execute()
    print(my_list[100])
except:
    #handle videoNotFound error
    #handle print(my_list[100]) if it raises an Index Error
```

Comment: You would possibly not get VideoNotFound error while inserting, right?

Comment: If you mean it's possible that the insert will run without getting an error, then yes that is the case.

Comment: No, I mean you won't get that error for insertion. You could get it for read/retrieving - that's how I understand it.

Comment: It's a possible error that you can get for the insert method as well, you can see it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer on the google api client for python [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/googleapiclient/errors.py).

```
import googleapiclient.errors
try:
    result = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part = "snippet",
        body = {
            "snippet": {
                "playlistId": MY_PLAYLIST_ID,
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": MY_VIDEO_ID
                }
            }
        }
    ).execute()
    print(my_list[100])
except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
    if e.error_details[0]["reason"] == "videoNotFound":
        print("Video not found.")
except IndexError:
    print("IndexError occurred")
```